# I am using the react-router-dom-v5-compat library to upgrade to v6 and am receiving browser errors when I import <CompatRouter> into my code

Tags: reactjs, react-router, migration, react-router-dom

I am currently running `react-router` and `react-router-dom` v5.3.4 and am following the guide to upgrade to v6. I have installed the `react-router-dom-v5-compat` compatibility library alongside side these and as per the guide on Github I have placed the `<CompatRouter>` below the `<BrowserRouter>` however this produces a browser error

> ./node_modules/react-router-dom-v5-compat/dist/index.js
> Attempted import error: 'AbortedDeferredError' is not exported from 'react-router'.

and console errors that are the same but for every other export of react-router in alphabetical order.

Commenting out the use of `<CompatRouter>` still produces the same error which narrows it down to the import statement itself which once commented out allows the app to render.

Placement of `<CompatRouter>` in index.js where we place `<BrowserRouter>`:

```js
loadMessages()
  .then((messages) => {
    const container = document.getElementById('root');
    const root = createRoot(container);
    root.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages} defaultLocale='en-gb'>
          <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <MaterialThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} adapterLocale={enGB}>
                  <InactivityLogoutProvider>
                    <Router>
                      <CompatRouter>
                        <App />
                      </CompatRouter>
                    </Router>
                  </InactivityLogoutProvider>
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </ThemeProvider>
            </MaterialThemeProvider>
          </StyledEngineProvider>
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  });
```

Package.json dependencies section

```json
"react-router": "^5.3.4",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
"react-router-dom-v5-compat": "^6.21.3",
```

I have narrowed the problem down to the import statement itself by commenting out the use of the `<CompatRouter>`. I have also tried updating the version of `react-router` to the same v6 version of the `react-router-dom-v5-compat` library to check if that was the issue.

Comment: `react-router-dom` re-exports all of `react-router`, so check if uninstalling `react-router` helps resolve the issue. If it doesn't, how much code do you have to migrate? It may be simpler to just complete the migration to v6.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the suggestion, I uninstalled react-router and tried running again, as soon as I uncommented the import of CompatRouter from react-router-dom-v5-compat I get same result.
We are carrying out the migration on an enterprise monolith app so wanted to avoid migration without the compat library if possible but maybe will just have to bite the bullet.